# Is this possible to wait for glRender() and glSwapBuffers() finished?

Tags: opengl

I noticed that when a key is pressed, and the redraw is initiated from the keyboard even function, the previous draw sometimes is not completely finished. The result is a sloppy "animation". I am basically scrolling the contents of the window. When I measure my `draw()` function I can see it takes `5 ms`. Which is more than enough for a smooth scrolling. But my guess is that the actual drawing is done asynchronously by OpenGL driver somewhere under the hood. So the question:

Can I get notified when the actual rendering and screen update is finished?

```
    function draw(ev) {
        var gl = GLX.renderPipeline();
        gl.Viewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.MatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.LoadIdentity();
        gl.Ortho(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1);
        gl.MatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.LoadIdentity();

        gl.ClearColor(0.3,0.3,0.8,0.0);
        gl.Clear(0x00004000|0x00000100);

        gl.Color4f(0, 0, 0.9, 0.5);
        rect(gl, 100, 100, 400, 300)

        var s = 'ATARI 65 XE FOREVER ATARI 65 XE FOREVER ATARI 65 XE FOREVER ATARI 65 XE FOREVER!'
        s = s + s
        s = s.split('')
        for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) s[i] = s[i].charCodeAt(0) + charListBegin
        for (var y = 0; y < 60; y++) {
           gl.LoadIdentity();
           gl.Translatef(charsX, charsY + y * fontSize*8, 0)
           gl.Color4f(colors[y][0], colors[y][1], colors[y][2], 0.5);
           gl.CallLists(s)
        }

        gl.Render(ctx);
        GLX.SwapBuffers(ctx, win);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, your commands are placed into a queue. The command queue is flushed at distinct points, for example when you call `SwapBuffers` or `glFlush` (but also on some other occasions, e.g. when the queue is full) and the commands are worked off asynchronously. Most commands simply post a command and return immediately, unless they have some lengthy work to do that cannot be postponed, like `glBufferData` performing a copy of a few hundred kilobytes into a buffer object (this is something that has to happen immediately too, because OpenGL cannot know if the data is still valid at a later time).  **The time it takes to post commands is what you measure, but it's not what you are interested in.**

If your GL version is at least 3.2, you can be "kind of notified" by calling `glFenceSync`, which inserts a fence object, and allows you to *block* until the fence has been realized using `glClientWaitSync`. When `glClientWaitSync` returns, all commands up to the fence have completed.

If you have at least version 3.3, you can *measure* the time your OpenGL commands take to render by inserting a query of type `GL_TIME_ELAPSED`. This works without blocking and is therefore by far the preferrable thing. **This is the actual time it takes to draw your stuff.**

`SwapBuffers`, like most commands, does *mostly nothing*. It will call `glFlush`, insert the equivalent of a fence, and mark the framebuffer as "locked, and ready to be swapped".

Eventually, when all draw commands have finished *and when the driver or window manager can be bothered* (think of vertical sync and compositing window managers!), the driver will unlock and swap buffers. **This is when your stuff actually gets visible.**
If you perform any other command in the mean time that would alter the locked frame buffer, the command blocks. This is what gives `SwapBuffers` the illusion of blocking.

You don't have much control over that (other than modifying the swap interval, if the implementation lets you) and you can't make it any faster -- but by playing with things like `glFlush` or `glFinish` you can make it slower.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you queue a redraw, instead of calling draw directly. I.e. when using Qt, you'd call `QWidget::update()`.

As far as waiting until all commands in the pipeline have been processed, you can call `glFinish()`, see https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glFinish.xml .